# Qual melhor pratica para resolver o problema com o git?

Tags: git

Seguinte, o cenário é: No meu trabalho tem um projeto com **apenas uma branch a master**. Tiveram commits que quebraram a versão que estava em produção. Então, quando eu peguei o projeto, precisei clonar o projeto em um commit especifico. Assim o fiz, clonei em um commit especifico, adicionei novas funcionalidades. Tenho algumas dúvidas, por exemplo:

- Como faço para subir a minha versão sem dar conflito? Eu pensei em criar uma nova branch mas perderia o historico, gostaria apenas de remover todos esses commits que quebraram a aplicação e voltar para a versão que eu baixei, para que eu consiga commitar.
- Tevo ter duas branches? Tipo uma master e uma para desenvolvimento?
- O que mais posso fazer?

Comment: _"Tevo ter duas branches? Tipo uma master e uma para desenvolvimento?"_ com certeza, na verdade até mais, desenvolvimento, teste, homologação e produção. Qual o problema de perder o histórico dos erros, se os commits quebraram a aplicação tem que ter eles salvos?

Comment: Se pesquisar por "git workflow" verá que existem inúmeras possibilidades diferentes, então a "melhor prática" depende de cada caso. Mas creio que não está aproveitando uma das grandes vantagens do git, que é justamente poder ter vários branches, já que eles são "baratos" e mais fáceis de fazer merge se comparado com svn, por exemplo. E vc sempre tem uma cópia de todo o repositório, não há receio de perder histórico - se bem que até mesmo o histórico não é considerado "sagrado" para os adeptos do rebase: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Answer (score 0):

Não existe uma melhor pratica que se aplique em todos os casos. O problema que você está enfrentando é a falta de branchs. Eu, por exemplo, trabalho da seguinte forma:

- Uma branch com o código que vai para produção, chamada **master**
- Uma para o homologação, chamada **staging**
- Uma nova branch a cada funcionalidade

Assim quando existe uma nova funcionalidade o processo fica assim:

- Criar uma branch à partir da **master**, exemplo **cadastro-de-usuarios**
- Depois de pronto para testes, fazer merge da **cadastro-de-usuarios** com a **staging**
- Depois de homologado, fazer merge da **cadastro-de-usuarios** com a **master**

Se esse histórico é importante para vocês é possivel criar uma nova branch que contenha ele e depois fazer um reset na master para o ultimo commit sem erros.

Exemplo de comandos para criar um backup da master e reseta-la:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b backup-master
git checkout master
git reset --hard HASH_DO_COMMIT_CORRETO
git push origin --force
```

Existem formas mais sofisticadas de organizar suas branchs, recomendo seguir o  mais simples para você e sua equipe. Também recomendo esse artigo sobre o git flow: [Git Flow](https://fjorgemota.com/git-flow-uma-forma-legal-de-organizar-repositorios-git/)

Há outra técnica chamada feature toggles, eu ainda não usei, mas é interessante: [Feature Toggles vs Feature Branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434222/feature-toggles-vs-feature-branches)